# Things to keep in mind to develop websites for Blackberry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blackberry

I need to develop a website that work on Blackberry.
Please suggest me the things which I should keep in mind to develop website on Blackberry and what all things are required to develop website for mobile (like public IP etc)

Following things are required in the website Please let me know how much these will be supported on Blackberry Browser:

1. Geolocation.
2. Google Maps API.
3. temporary local storage (for text data).
4. Ajax.

Please let me know how much HTML5 support is available on Blackberry Browsers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Ajax is supported with the Blackberry Browser. You most likely won't be able to do everything in a fancy way, so be wary of that. I've also noticed that there are a ton of CSS limitations too.

Also keep in mind that some Blackberrys only support up to certain version of CSS, Javascript etc. There are lots of documentation on what is and what is not supported. Here is an example:

[General overview of the Javascript supported](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Feature_JavaScript_512506_11.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

What is your background concerning web development? Regardless of your skill you should take a look at these two links.

[Mobile best practices](http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/mobile-web-design-tips-and-best-practices.html)

This is a must read for anyone serious about developing for the web. There are so many experienced developers who don't follow these essential practices.

[Yahoo! Best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)